# Heroku - Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) - Python - вопрос

Tags: python, heroku

Я недавно выложил своего бота на heroku, всё хорошо работает, но просматривая логи, я увидел ошибку, которая встречается довольно часто:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Cам бот занимает  67 мб, хотя и может расширяться на условные 75 мб( бот качает 15 фотографий(5 мб макс вес фото) каждый раз, когда выполняется определённая команда). Далее, при её повторном выполнении, фотографии заменяют друг друга, поэтому тут проблем не должно быть. И стоит отметить, что сам бот функционирует абсолютно нормально, но данные ошибки меня беспокоят. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А `top` что говорит или там нельзя `top` посмотреть?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Не совсем понимаю

Comment: Ну, сколько процессы едят памяти. Чем вы смотрите, сколько занимает бот?